# Django: I have to login to admin site before the application

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a weird problem with my Django application and I have no idea where to look to fix it. Whenever I run my application, before I can login to the application and do stuff on it I have to login to the admin site or else it throws a "Page not found (404)" error when I try to login to the application as a normal (non-admin) user.

Any ideas on what may be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: You have a couple of options; Sebastian's answer has some decent suggestions.  If they don't work, I'd suggest creating a dummy django app and add bits of your current settings.py until you either get all the functionality you need back or can post a minimal complete example

Answer (score 2):

This might happen due to the following combination of circumstances:

1. The view you are accessing requires authentication (check for the `@login_required` decorator on the view)
2. Therefore, when you access anonymously it is trying to redirect you to the login page (check your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting in `settings.py`)
3. Then, when your browser tries to reach this login page, it is not found (404)

So remove `@login_required` if it isn't really necessary, or make sure your login redirect is well configured and pointing to a url that actually provides a login page.